# Adding a Custom Action to List View in Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am following below article and was able to add custom action to a library. But unable to do so for List as I do not know the location. I want to get the same location of Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Controls._children"> for a list. Is there a guide with locations applicable to modern list view?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries

```
<pnp:CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Controls._children">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.OfficeDevPnPDownloadAll"
            Command="OfficeDevPnP.Cmd.DownloadAll"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/sharepointfoundation16.png"
            LabelText="Download All"
            Description="Download all files separately"
            ToolTipTitle="Download All"
            ToolTipDescription="Download all files separately"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
            Sequence="15"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="OfficeDevPnP.Cmd.DownloadAll"
          CommandAction="https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/pages/index.aspx" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </pnp:CommandUIExtension>
```

Comment: change the `Location and <Button Id` to `<button id="Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children""` and check

Comment: @GautamSheth Does not work in modern experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children` for `Location`

**MSDN References :**

[Default Server Ribbon Customization Locations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537543(v=office.14).aspx)

[CustomAction Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460194.aspx)

Comment: This does not work in modern experience. This only works in classic mode and appears as a list item action, not a list action.

Comment: try this CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView

Comment: I assume that is for CustomAction location and  not CommandUIDefinition location. Yeah it is working on classic mode. But not in modern experience.

Comment: It works. There was an error in my CommandUIDefinition .